# XAML inline value assignement

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I just wondered if  its possible to write this line of code in a Single "inline" line:

```
<Ellipse MinWidth="10" MinHeight="10" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=SelectedColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Primitives:ColorPickerBase}}}" />
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

i.e. Setting the `Fill` Property in the definition of the `Ellipse` to a new `SolidBrush` with its `Color` Property template bound

Update 1: Adriano correctly mentioned the possibility of a `ValueConverter` from `Color` to `SolidBrush` in the Comments. I was aware of this possibility but I was looking for a one line solution without any extra code elsewhere.

Comment: Writing your own value converter. That said...is it useful? It won't be reused for anything else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this because Fill property of `Ellipse` is of `SolidColorBrush Type` and what is you have is `Color Type` for binding. So in the end you need a `converter` that can Convert the Color to SolidColorBrush or a Property of type SolidColorBrush.

I think the way you are using it won't be problem. :)

Comment: Thanks, I have this snippet quite often and I'm looking to reduce code to make it cleaner. If it cannot be done in a single line, I'll have to reconsider the ValueConverter Method